# Tensorflow tanh with quantized values

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

I am experimenting with the quantization of a neural network in Tensorflow 1.1.

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/tanh), the `tanh` operation supports floating point inputs as well as fixed point inputs of type `qint32`. However, I can't get this to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.constant([1.,2.,3.], dtype=tf.float32)

from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_array_ops import quantize_v2
x_quant = quantize_v2(x, min_range=0., max_range=4., T=tf.qint32)

y_quant = tf.nn.tanh(x_quant[0])
```

The code yields an error message:

> ```
> TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType qint32 not in list of 
> allowed values: float16, float32, float64, complex64, complex128
> ```

Is there a way out or is it just a bug in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug in doc. According to the backend function `_tanh` in `gen_math_ops.py`:

> ```
> def _tanh(x, name=None):
>   r"""Computes hyperbolic tangent of `x` element-wise.
>
>   Args:
>     x: A `Tensor`. Must be one of the following types: `half`, `float32`, `float64`, `complex64`, `complex128`.
>     name: A name for the operation (optional).
> ```

Since quantization is really new, perhaps the new version of `_tanh` is still in progress.

Comment: After looking through the file history, I can confirm that this is a bug in the docs that was introduced back in July 2015, before we'd released and when the quantization definition wasn't completely nailed down.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! So what would be the most straightforward way to quantize inference for a network that uses tanh activation function?